# Google Cloud Vertex AI API not recognising PaLM model

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline, palm-api

I am currently trying to implement Google's PaLM API into python using the vertexai module. However I run into an error where my code does not recognise the model name (model is called 'chat-bison@001').

The code snippet of what I have tried doing is posted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89e1F.png), along with the error message. The code works fine when i change the 'location' parameter to 'us-central1' but I'm not sure why it does not compile with the location set to 'australia-southeast1'. As far as I'm aware, PaLM is supported in Australia as well.

Answer (score 1):

For now, models are only deployed in us-central1. You can also test this beta API, but no location is mentioned in the URL: https://developers.generativeai.google/api/rest/generativelanguage